# Ionic 2 Runtime Error No Porvider

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2

I have created a provider file called data-list.ts

Included it in my app.moudule.ts

```
   import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'angular2-infinite-scroll';

import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { AuthServiceProvider } from '../providers/auth-service/auth-service';
import { JobsServiceProvider } from '../providers/jobs-service/jobs-service';
import { DataListProvider } from '../providers/data-list/data-list';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  MyApp,
  LoginPage,
  AboutPage,
  ContactPage,
  HomePage,
  TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  HttpModule,
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
  InfiniteScrollModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
  MyApp,
  LoginPage,
  AboutPage,
  ContactPage,
  HomePage,
  TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
  StatusBar,
  SplashScreen,
  {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
  JobsServiceProvider,
  DataListProvider 
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and in my file where i want to use it (home.ts) and included it in my constructor

```
import { DataListProvider } from '../../providers/data-list/data-list';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public DataListProvider: DataListProvider) {}
```

but I keep getting this error, what am I missing :

> MyApp_Host.html:1 ERROR Error: No provider for DataListProvider!
>       at injectionError (core.es5.js:1231)
>       at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1269)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2770)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2809)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKey (core.es5.js:2741)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.get (core.es5.js:2610)
>       at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (core.es5.js:3557)
>       at resolveDep (core.es5.js:11017)
>       at createClass (core.es5.js:10881)
>       at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10701)

Comment: Have you added `@Injectable()` in your service class `DataListProvider`?

Comment: yes I have added it

Comment: please update the question again with your `DataListProvider.ts` code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the provider to the NgModule, i.e module.ts under providers,

```
providers: [
  DataListProvider
]
```

Comment: as you can see in my question I already added the providers in  my ngModule

Comment: sorry I realised I misunderstood, I added it , but I still get the same error

Comment: can you post again what is inside the module.ts

Comment: change your constructor as constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public dataListProvider: DataListProvider)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146399/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-noor).

Answer (score 0):

you need to add DataListProvider to list of provider in app.moudule.ts like this:

```
 import { DataListProvider } from '../providers/data-list/data-list';

      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
        JobsServiceProvider,
        DataListProvider 
      ]
```

Comment: you can try to add this provider in your home.js page
@Component({
  selector: '*****',
  templateUrl: '****',
  providers: [DataListProvider]
})

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to convert 'DataListProvider' into an injectable:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataListProvider() {
 // Content Service
}
```

Then import it into the list of @NgModule providers in app.module.ts:

```
import {DataListProvider} from '../providers/data-list/data-list';

providers: [
 StatusBar,
 SplashScreen,
 {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
 JobsServiceProvider,
 DataListProvider 
]
```

If this solution does not work for you, you can try converting the Home component into a module:

```
import {NgModule, ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import {Home} from './home';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
  declarations: [Home],
  exports: [Home]
})
export class HomeModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: HomeModule
    };
  }
}
```

and import that module into the @NgModule:

```
import {HomeModule} from './home.module.ts';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  MyApp,
  LoginPage,
  AboutPage,
  ContactPage,
  TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  HttpModule,
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
  InfiniteScrollModule,
  HomeModule.forRoot()  // -> New Module
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
  MyApp,
  LoginPage,
  AboutPage,
  ContactPage,
  TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
  StatusBar,
  SplashScreen,
  {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
  JobsServiceProvider,
  DataListProvider 
  ]
})
```

Hope this can help you!